# Getting Error: Module parse failed: ... unexpected character '#'

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, redux

I am using webpack for the first time and want to use some css with my react/redux application. I followed a guide, but still seem to be having problems. I am getting the above error as you can see.

folder structure looks like this:

```
.git
-node_modules
-public
 -bundle.js
 -index.html
-src
 -actions
 -components
 -reducers
 app.js
-style
 -style.css
.babelrc
.gitingore
package-lock.json
package.json
README.md
server.js
webpack.config.js
```

This is the exact error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: C:\Users\Amazo\projects\reduxApp\style\style.css Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| #row1 {
|   margin-top: 15px;
| }
```

I will post my webpack config file below:

```
var path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
  },
  watch: true,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude:/node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
        }
      },
      {
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        test: /\.css$/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js','.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'public/index.html';
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
  ]
};
```

Comment: Try to add `.css` inside the `extensions` array

Comment: I did try that and it did not work. Here is the REPO in case that helps https://github.com/tbaustin/test_react_redux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `.css` to your `resolve`

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js','.jsx', '.css']
},
```

Otherwise, webpack won't be able to process it correctly

Comment: I will put the github repo here to make things easier =]
https://github.com/tbaustin/test_react_redux

Comment: Okay I had a typo in the webpack file, in the plugins I had a ; in an object so it was stopping webpack from reloading when I added the css, thank you!